# class library with multiple nuget packages issue

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a class library with numerous projects, each referencing each other, written in C#. This is a common library that I share with other projects. I have recently changed the mechanism that the library is shared to be via nuget. So for each project within the library, I have a post build event to create a nuget package eg.

```
"$(SolutionDir)\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectPath)" -o "$(SolutionDir)\Packages"
```

This works nicely. It pushes the package to a shared folder in the file structure and the consuming project installs it from there. All projects packages are pushed to this folder.

I have ran in to a problem though. Lets say my library creates package X and Y. X has a reference to Y in the class library. In the consuming application, I need to use X, when I install it, it doesnt install the ddl from Y. I also need to install package Y. How can I set it up when package X is created, it also includes the necessary dlls's from package Y, without having to explicitly install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the nuspec file of package X you can specify package Y as dependency

<dependencies> 
      <dependency id="Y" version="1.0" />
</dependencies>

More options around dependency can be found here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies

For specifying files you could use
<files>
  <file src="bin\Debug*.dll" target="lib" /> 
  <file src="bin\Debug*.pdb" target="lib" /> 
  
</files>
More details here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Files_to_Include_in_the_Package

Comment: Can you specify dlls as dependencies and will they get referenced in the consuming project?